# How to display push message in firefox when mysql table has a new record

Tags: php, mysql, notifications

I have a mysql table named notification with this structure

```
id   user_id    time    name
```

I want to display a push message when this table has been updated if `user_id` is same width user id of that user has been logged in
but i don't know how to do this

I tried to do that with this tutorial https://wiki.mozilla.org/WebAPI/SimplePush but i failed

Is there any other way to play a sound and show the notification ? please help me about this problem

Comment: Is your question about SimplePush or how to avoid SimplePush? Can you please tell us what you have tried so far, and exactly where it is failing? Where in the tutorial did you get stuck?

Comment: not about simple push did you test web.skype.com ? in web version of skype notifications of skype displayed as a push message in firefox or chrome with a sound i want to display a notification to user when he/she got a new record in database

Comment: Have you looked into WebSockets? I think that's the technology you're looking for.

Comment: @JosefEngelfrost no idon't want this please check this link

Comment: @JosefEngelfrost no idon't want this please check this link i want to only display a notification for user to notice him/her for new orders such as this image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4jCBqX2h4DPNl9LYzBFRnBqcm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In that case this sounds like a project to me. I recommend that you take the SO tour if you have not done so already (stackoverflow.com/tour), and then break down your project into several seperate questions. If you do this you will probably find that some have already been asked and answered, and more people are likely to help you when your questions are well defined.